# Is it possible to get strokes from a canvas with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using this drawing app: http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

I'm trying to get the stroke 'content' with: `var ctx = colors_sketch.getContext("2d");`

I'm looking for something that enables me to capture and redraw the canvas context. Like this:

```
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
// ... lots of lineTo's etc ...
ctx.lineTo(70,100);
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Not sure if it exist. But you can wrap those `moveTo`, `lineTo` to your custom function, and store them in array or something else, and only call the actual `moveTo`, `lineTo` when you call your customized `stroke()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom wrapper, and call its api to store the drawing operations in array, and when you done, use its api to stroke on canvas.

The wrapper would become mor complex than the snippet if you also intend to wrap other drawing operations like `arcTo, bezierCurveTo, rect ...` etc. But idea remains the same: Save the operations to a store with specific format, then when you're about to draw them on canvas, use ctx operations to replay those operations.

```js
var StokeStore = function() {
  this.store = [];
  this.current = [];
}

StokeStore.prototype.moveTo = function(x, y) {
  if (this.current.length !== 0) {
    this.store.push(this.current);
    this.current = [];
  }
  this.current.push({x: x, y: y});
};

StokeStore.prototype.lineTo = function(x, y) {
  this.current.push({x: x, y: y});
};

StokeStore.prototype.stroke = function(ctx, style) {
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = style ? style : 'black';
  this.store.forEach(function(line) {
    this._stroke(line);
  }, this);
  this._stroke(this.current);
  ctx.stroke();
};

StokeStore.prototype._stroke = function(line) {
    var length = line.length;
    if (length < 2) {
       return;
    }
    ctx.moveTo(line[0].x, line[0].y);
    var index, pt;
    for (index = 1; index < length; ++index) {
      pt = line[index];
      ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);
    }
};

var canvas = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var print = document.getElementById('print');
var clear = document.getElementById('clear');

var exampleStroke = new StokeStore();
exampleStroke.moveTo(50, 50);
exampleStroke.lineTo(70, 70);
exampleStroke.lineTo(200, 50);
exampleStroke.lineTo(200, 190);
exampleStroke.moveTo(30, 90);
exampleStroke.lineTo(0, 290);
exampleStroke.lineTo(290, 40);
exampleStroke.lineTo(150, 150);

var randomColor = ['red', 'cyan', 'black', 'purple'];

print.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length);
  var style = randomColor[rnd];
  exampleStroke.stroke(ctx, style);
});

clear.addEventListener('click', function() {
 canvas.width = canvas.width;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="print">print</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Update to [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke)'s comment:

I'm not good at modifying jQuery plugins, but it seems [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) do provide a storage itself, when you call its api, it sets `data-sketch` attribute to store its created instance, so you can try to interact with that instance, like its redraw or else.

Also, it use a similar format to store the sketch history, if we use `var sketch = $(CANVAS).data('sketch')` to get the instance, we can use `sketch.actions` to get all stroke, and each stroke has an `array` called `events`, which stores Objects with attribute `x, y, eventType`, so if you want, you can either retrieve the strokes from it, or put your own stroke into the history. Like:

```
sketch.actions.push({
    color: //stroke color,
    size: // stroke size,
    tool: // marker will draw, while eraser will erase to white,
    events: [
      {x:xval, y:yval, event:evType},....
    ]
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm2und8o/2/) or snippet below.

```js
$(function() {
    var $cv = $('#test');
    var cv = $cv.get(0);
    $('#test').sketch();
    var sketch = $cv.data('sketch');
  
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        cv.width = cv.width;
    });
  
    $('#redraw').click(function() {
        sketch.redraw();
    });
    
    $('#strokes').click(function() {
        var $display = $('#display').empty();
  sketch.actions.forEach(function(strk, idx) {
            if (!strk.events) {
             return;
            }
         var $div = $('<div>').addClass('stroke');
            $('<div>').text('Stroke #' + idx).appendTo($div);
            strk.events.forEach(function(pt, idx) {
                $("<p>").text(idx + ': (' + pt.x + ',' + pt.y + ')'  ).appendTo($div);
            });
            $div.appendTo($display);
        });
    });
  });
```

```css
#test {
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.stroke {
    border: solid 1px blue;
     float : left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/intridea/sketch.js/master/lib/sketch.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="test" width="500" height="500;"></canvas>
  
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<button id="redraw">redraw</button>
<button id="strokes">print strokes</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution of recording the strokes for later replaying is good -- upvote. In addition,I think the questioner also wants your ability integrated into the SketchJS framework (http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/).

Comment: @markE Thx for the advice, somehow I have not much experience with modifying jQuery plugin, but after read its source code, I get some way that maybe able retrieve/insert stroke with that lib, not sure if it's what OP want.